# Prove that $l(\tau\sigma n^{(-1/2)})$ tends to $\chi^2_1(\tau^2)$

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots ,X_n$ are i.i.d. sample with $E(X_1) = 0$ and $E(X_1^2) = \sigma^2 < \infty$. How can we prove that $l(\tau\sigma n^{-1/2})$ tends to $\chi^2_1(\tau^2)$?

Here $l(·)$ is the empirical likelihood ratio given by $l(\mu)=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log\{1+\lambda(X_i-\mu)\}$ for $\lambda$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i-\mu}{1+\lambda(X_i-\mu)}=0$.

Comment: That "help" in the title would do nothing for you other than making it less informative.

Comment: ¿¿¿$=2<1$??? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Gigili Look who's there!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments!  The question has been corrected.